# Routing Error - Railscasts #241 Simple OmniAuth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

HI all!
I am a newbie in Rails, big thanks for your help in anvanced!(Answering this probably naive question)

I tried to follow "Railscasts #241 Simple OmniAuth" to learn how to sign in with twitter, but I get a Routing Error every time. I really don't know what happened here.

```
No route matches "/test"
```

Here's my complete file and code structure:
[The Codes](http://www.ccool.idv.tw/questions/RoutingError.zip)

Thanks,
Howard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're redirecting to a non-existant test controller and you haven't set up your routes. Have a look at your sessions controller and your routes.rb file.

Looking at the tutorial you're following, you should have this in your sessions controller:

```
def create  
  ...
  redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed in!"  
end
```

you have this:

```
def create
  redirect_to(:controller => 'test', :action => 'index') 
end
```

In your routes.rb you should have

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do |map|  
  root :to => "articles#index"  

  match "/auth/:provider/callback" => "sessions#create"  

  resources :comments  
  resources :articles  
end
```

and you have

```
FsApiTest::Application.routes.draw do

  match "/auth/twitter/callback" => "sessions#create"
```

I personally prefer reading the written versions of these tutorials, btw:
http://asciicasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've checked the settings and still don't know what happened. Here's my server console message: Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (0.6ms)

And user wildcard route settting, could the error be here?

Comment: Thank you Mark! I think it's because I played around rails before I fully understand how things works in rails. I followed the tutorial again and find everything works fine~ I think the problem is on me, again, BIG THANKS FOR YOUR HELP!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding testcontroller in config/routes.rb